# Are there any two identical terms in this series, defined parallely to the primes?

Tags: sequences-and-series, elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers

Let $p_n$ denote $n$-th prime number and $k_n$ be sequence that is

\begin{align}
k_1 &= 1 \\
k_2 &= p_2 - k_1 &&( 3-1 = 2 ) \\
k_n &= p_n - k_{n-1} &&\text{( n is integer larger than 1 )}
\end{align}

this is result
$$1 , 2 , 3 , 4 , 7 , 6 , 11 , 8 , 15 , 14 , 17 , 20 , 21
, 22 , 25 , 28 , 31 , 30 , 37 , 34 , 39 , 40 , 43 , 46
, 51 , 50 , 53 , 54 , 55 , 58 , 69 , 62 , 75 , 64 , 85
, 66 , 91 , 72 , 95 , 78 , 101 , 80 , 111 , 82 , 115 ...$$

This is not a monotonically increasing sequence. My question is if there are two identical terms in this series. My guess is no.
Until $k_{200}$ still no special case appeared and until $k_{1000}$ and $k_{20000}$ too, 
I want to know that when is the first time the case appears?
I'm young kid and just curious but i belive that you smart people can solve this.

Comment: @Moo he said in the first sentence, $p_n$ is the $n^{th}$ prime number.  @ Sury Bury, this appears as [oeis/A036467](http://oeis.org/A036467).

Comment: As the OEIS comments say, there are no duplicate values because they alternate even/odd, and each term is greater than the previous term of the same parity.

Comment: thanks alot, I was looking for this.

Comment: Good question. Did you arrive at this question on your own ?

Comment: Does the OP mean no two numbers next to each other are equal or that no two terms anywhere are equal to each other.

Comment: I edited your question. Please check if the meaning is the same. Am I the only one who's surprised that this series is not a monotonically increasing one ?

Comment: This is a good question. Don't know why it's getting downvoted.

Comment: @fleablood I think he means anywhere

Comment: @user230452 I did too. But f" seems to think s/he means adjacent.

Comment: Why in the blue blazes was this closed?  It's absolutely clear what is being asked.  It's a good question.  The op explained what s/he had done to the best of his/her ability.

Comment: @user230452 I was a little surprised but not astonished.  When you have a prime pair you have $k_{n+1} = p_{n+1} - k{n} = (p_n + 2) - (p_n - k_{n_1}) = 2 + k_{n - 1}$ which would require $k_{n} = k_{n+1} - 1 = k_{n-1} + 1$ to be monotonically increasing which ... doesn't seem nescessary.

Answer (score 2):

Suppose $k_n = k_{n+1}$.

Then $k_n = p_{n+1} - k_n$ so $2k_n = p_{n+1}$.  Thus $p_{n+1}$ is an even prime.  $p_1 = 2$ is the only even prime and that can not happen as $n > 1$.  So this never happens.

Note $k_{n} = p_n - k_{n-1}$.  As $p_n$ is odd and "odd - odd = even" and "odd - even = odd".  The terms must switch from odd to even every turn.

Suppose $k_n = k_{n + i}$....

Let's look closer at what $k_n$ *is*.

$k_1 = 1$

$k_2 = p_2 - 1$

$k_3 = p_3 - p_2 + 1$

$k_4 = p_4 - p_3 + p_2 - 1$

....

$k_n = p_n - p_{n-1} + ....+p_2 -1 $  if $n$ is even.

$k_n = p_n - p_{n-1} + ....-p_2 +1 $  if $n$ is even.

So if $k_n = k_{n+i}$ because odd and even alternate $i$ is even and $k_n = k_{n+i}$ are either both even or both odd.

So $k_n = p_n - ..... \pm p_2 \mp 1$ and $k_{n+i}= p_{n+ i} - ..... \pm p_2 \mp 1$

$k_{n+i} = k_n \implies k_{n+i} - k_n = 0 \implies (p_{n+ i} - p_{n+i - 1}) + (p_{n+i - 2} - p_{n+i - 3}) + .... + (p_{n+2} - p_{n-1})=0$.

As $p_k > p_{k-1}$ each of the terms in parenthesis is positive.  So $k_{n+i} - k_n > 0$.

So this sequence will never repeat.

Comment: Why not just note that (by induction) $k_n$ is odd for $n$ odd and even for $n$ even, and then calculate $k_n=p_n-k_{n-1}=p_n-(p_{n-1}-k_{n-2})=(p_n-p_{n-1})+k_{n-2}\gt k_{n-2}$?

Comment: If that's easier for you.  Go for it. .... But isn't that basically what I did?

Answer (score 0):

Fleablood took care of the details of the proof. So, I'll just offer some exposition on his proof.

We split your series into two different series. One series consisting of odd terms $O$ , and one series consisting of even terms, $E$. We discover, (quite delightfully) that both $O$ and $E$ are monotonically increasing sequences, even if $K=\{k_n\}_0^\infty$ is not ! So, all terms in $E$ and $O$ are unique.

Now, it just remains to be shown that these two sequences never intersect. This is easily done.